# Beginner PW Question using MacOS terminal

Tags: server, ssh, login

I started working through the application process for a bootcamp today and came across an issue that is probably very elementary, however since I am a complete newbie I am lost!

I was able to log onto a server once without issues. I closed my laptop and moved locations, when I went into MacOS terminal I added the server address no problem. It asked for the pw once, said "permission denied, please try again" the second time inputting the server pw the system came back with the following message:

```
*** System restart required ***
--- Your logging code is 7067b799 ---
Last login: Thu Feb 10 23:13:56 2022 from 179.12.56.44
root@ip-10-250-29-217:~# ssh root@34.233.135.225
root@34.233.135.225's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1128-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

4 packages can be updated.
2 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

New release '18.04.6 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Any idea what I can do to move past this?

Comment: That's just information letting you know what needs to be done, like the reboot for the new kernel or driver that needs a reboot to happen.  Or the updates need to be ran.  Or you can run the upgrade from 16.04, which actually is no longer supported because it is EOL, to 18.04LTS which is supported.  You probably want to try running the last command you see there of `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: What are you getting now that restart has been completed? is it still saying *** System restart required ***?

Comment: I upgraded the system to 20.04.3 and it does not say *** System restart required*** anymore. It asks for my pw and gives the same message "Welcome to Ubuntu..." without logging into the server.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you will need to restart the server in order to apply kernel updates. You can do this with:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

However, Ubuntu 16.04 is long out of support. If you do not have the Extended Security Maintenance packages running, then you will need to upgrade to 18.04 or something newer. As this is an AWS instance, it would probably be easier to simply build a fresh machine with 20.04.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried the command you gave me and was able to close the connection with the server but I am still at the same problem.I am levels behind building a new machine and this server is from the bootcamp school, I do not have the knowledge yet to build a new machine or even know how to apply kernel updates.