# Upgraded Ubuntu, now password to get into server will not work

Tags: server, ssh, login

I asked a similar question yesterday here, I am on a deadline and really out of my depth so any help would be hugely appreciated:

[Beginner PW Question using MacOS terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392258/beginner-pw-question-using-macos-terminal?noredirect=1#comment2407373_1392258)

I updated the system to the 20.04.3 install and now whenever I try logging into the ssh server, it asks for the pw but once I input it all I receive is the following message without a successful login:

```
root@34.233.135.225's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-1028-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Fri 11 Feb 2022 12:30:27 PM UTC

  System load:  0.0               Processes:             109
  Usage of /:   26.6% of 9.63GB   Users logged in:       1
  Memory usage: 26%               IPv4 address for eth0: 10.250.29.217
  Swap usage:   0%

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


--- Your logging code is 7067b799 ---
Last login: Fri Feb 11 12:24:15 2022 from 179.12.56.44
root@ip-10-250-29-217:~#
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem here. You've signed in.

Comment: You have no problem !! The server tells you that  the system is up to date and other standard information.Then you get a Shell (root) prompt. You are ready to go ... what are you missing or expecting to happen ?

Answer (score 3):

That is the very picture of a successful login, complete with shell prompt awaiting your command.

Advice: The question suggests that you might be a very new user. I advise against using the root account. New + Root = high risk of breaking your system through your own folly. Root has superpowers and no protections.

We did try to warn you....

Comment: The reason I doubt I am logged in is because I am supposed to use the "cd" command to figure out the path of the working directory, but nothing happens it just repeats this: "root@ip-10-250-29-217:~#". Yes, I am very, very new to this! And I might have already screwed the whole thing up. Thanks

Comment: Trust me,  I feel like a fool at the moment. This is a task to apply to get into a bootcamp so I am very, very wet behind the ears. The question I am trying to answer is "Type cd and hit Enter. Once done, what is the path to your working directory?" and I've tried different variations of "root@ip-10-250-29-217:~#" with no success. Can you guide me with a way to find an answer or clarification?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/357893 for a clear explanation of what the `cd` command does and how to determine your current working directory.

Comment: Thank you very much! That answered my question!